# String to DateTime convert during CV StreamReader (C#)

Tags: c#, date, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-conversion

I got issue with convert string to date, during **StreamReader**:

```
string line;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.ToString());
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
 string col13 = line.Split(',')[13]; //"22/06/2014 00:00:00"    
}
```

I have tried below code and I got error:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.Parse(col13); 
//or
DateTime y = Convert.ToDateTime(col13);
//System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime tempDate = Convert.ToDateTime(col13, culture);
//System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

DateTime y = DateTime.ParseExact(col13, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//System.FormatException: 'DateTime pattern 'm' appears more than once with different values.'
```

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy` -> Did you intend to include minutes in your date format? Or did you mean months (`MM`)?

Comment: `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`, please, note `M` for month and `H` in (`0..23` range)  for hour

Comment: perfect, thank you, you can put this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DateTime.ParseExact()` format, instead of `mm` use `MM`

From MSDN,

- [MM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MM_Specifier)

> The "MM" custom format specifier represents the month as a number from
>   01 through 12

- [mm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#mmSpecifier)

> The "mm" custom format specifier represents the minute as a number
>   from 00 through 59.

So, your `DateTime.ParseExact()` will be

```
DateTime y = DateTime.ParseExact(col13, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                          //^^      ^^ This needs to update
```